# Android in app billing

Tags: android, billing

I just have one product which is for removing Ads. I implemented all methods that provided by Google's example. I have crash on here :

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                }
                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });
```

it says :

```
In-app billing error: Illegal state for operation (queryInventory): IAB helper is not set up.
```

I have `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>` in my Manifest file. Also I implemented `onActivityResult`.

This is my product that I setup it on the Google console : 
[image]

I red the Google doc and it said your in app billing should be published. I just changed its status to active and im not sure if that is the way to publish it.

Can anymore tell me what is going wrong ? thanks

EDIT :

Also when the result is not successful, the result is :

```
IabResult: Error checking for billing v3 support. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your code has an error: you call queryInventoryAsync even if the result has no success. It should be changed like this:

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                }
                else {   <================= HERE!!
                    // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!    
                    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
                }
            }
        });
```

Regarding the settings in the dashboard, you correctly registered the in app product, but you also need to publish at least one version of the app in ALPHA, BETA or PRODUCTION channel (I suggest to start with some testing in Alpha, so no one will see it). Did you do that?

Comment: Thanks, I uploaded a BETA test APK but again because I've never done this before I was confused that if i publish it the whole app is gonna publish.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed this problem by :

- Published BETA APK on the Google Console
- Updated the Google Play Services on my device
- Removed the Play Store's cache on the device